# Detect debugger in c++ with zero division exception

Tags: c++, debugging, inline-assembly

I found function written in c++ which is able to detect debugger when I execute

```
xor eax, eax
div eax
```

but the problem is when a debugger is attached the process crashes after reaching `div eax`. I put that inline asm to __try and __except section but after reaching instruction `div eax` process just freezes. Whole code:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

LONG WINAPI UnhandledExcepFilter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExcepPointers) {
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter((LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER)pExcepPointers->ContextRecord->Eax);
    pExcepPointers->ContextRecord->Eip += 2;
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}

int main() {
     SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(UnhandledExcepFilter);

    __try {
        __asm {
            xor eax, eax
            div eax
        }
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO) {
        cout << "DEBUGGER NOT FOUND" << endl;
    }

return NULL;
}
```

I need just silently detect debugger.
Thx for any help.

Comment: Nitpick: `NULL` may not be an `int` value. If you mean `EXIT_SUCCESS`, write `EXIT_SUCCESS`, or if you mean `0` write `0`

Comment: it works with NULL, anyway thats not primary problem....

Comment: There're lot of papers around how anti-debugging techniques work, so take google, read and understand what you find.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are using `"windows.h"`, you can simplify it to [`IsDebuggerPresent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345(v=vs.85).aspx), and / or [`DebugBreak`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: IsDebuggerPresent can be easily bypassed and DebugBreak has same result, DebugBreak=int 3 (its same in disassembly)

Comment: @Caleth at a stab, I'd guess that they're trying to prevent debuggers being attached - but then clearly stripping the exe's would be the better way forward.

Comment: `IsDebuggerPresent` can be easilly hooked, better is to call manulay `NtQueryInformationProcess`